# Use Express API as backend for an electron app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, electron

I currently have a simple application consisting of an express api in the backend, and a react frontend.

I now want to turn this into a desktop app (electron) that works fully offline, without rewriting all the code.

The Frontend doesn't seem to be a problem since I can use the same react components. However, I'm not sure how to implement the backend. Can I just take my express code and put it into the electron app? I've seen examples that successfully did that, but the frontend communicated with the backend through a local Port which doesn't seem good practice?

Comment: Or you can use express hosted on your server side, if you don't want to use localhost on your machine.